# Check for empty rowset in oci_fetch_array

Tags: php, oracle-call-interface

I am doing the following...

```
$approved = oci_parse($conn_prs, "select * from patch_files where patch_reviewer = '". $_SESSION['id'] ."' and patch_status = 'Approved'"); // now rows available for current id
oci_execute($approved);
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($approved, OCI_BOTH  + OCI_RETURN_NULLS )) {
var_dump($row); // shows nothing
if ($row == null) { echo "<p>None Found...</p>"; }
else { ....
```

Not sure why the null condition is not working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your null condition is not working because `$row` is never `null`.  `oci_fetch_array()` returns an array of the row fields, or `false`. If there are no rows your `while` loop is not executed.

You seem to have misunderstood the purpose of `OCI_RETURN_NULLS`.  When used, it creates array elements for empty *fields* in `$row`, not an empty array if there are no rows.

A quick and dirty way to do what you want is:

```
$i = 0;
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($approved, OCI_BOTH  + OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
    $i++;
    ...
}
if ($i == 0) {
    echo "<p>None Found...</p>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try with -

```
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($approved, OCI_BOTH  + OCI_RETURN_NULLS )) {
   var_dump($row); // shows nothing
   if (empty($row)) { echo "<p>None Found...</p>"; }
   else { ....
```

`oci_fetch_array()` - returns the next row from a query as an array.

Comment: `var_dump($row)` prints nothing??

Comment: var_dump($row) prints nothing...works fine when there is a laptop.